# Visual Basic Order of Operations

Tags: vba, math, operator-precedence, legacy-code

I'm trying to rewrite a legacy Visual Basic app into a web app, and I've been going through the math of it and I've come across an oddity that I can't quite figure out:

`return (x) * 1 / y`

Now, from what I'm reading, the way this should execute is `(x * 1) / y` or rather `x / y` but that `1` is confusing me. If I were putting that `1` there I'd only do so if I was implying:

`return x * (1 / y)`

So, am I reading into this too much and assuming the 1 is there unnecessarily or is it actually an important part of the function?

Comment: See that's exactly what my understanding is, I'm just apprehensive about making that assumption since this program works (as far as I'm aware) and typically one doesn't add an extra "* 1" to something unless it does something.

Comment: What is the type of `x`?

Comment: Both X and Y are Decimals

Comment: FYI that the literal `1` is first interpreted as a 16bit integer only to implicitly be implicitly converted later as needed. I am curious if this might be a hack to avoid an `Overflow` error. Maybe `Decimal/Decimal` does not produce the result expected.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! Thankfully we are switching to Javascript and that issue shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for the info!

Comment: In cases like this i'd probably write a test app that picks maybe a million or hundred million pairs of random decimals and runs the calculation with different parentheses and with/without 1 and see if any differences are detected. If you suspect any specific edge cases you can try those deterministically too. I think the parentheses and 1 are most likely vestigial and not there intentionally. Is the code version controlled? There might be some indication in the history of why it looks that way.